# Reading message sent before start?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

*The Erlang RMQ server runs non-stop*.

Let's say I have a RMQ receiver and RMQ sender which sends a message right from the start.

When I start them: receiver first, sender second, the message is sent and server picks it up.

But when I start sender first, and right after it sends its message, I start receiver, receiver does not see that message.

My question is is RMQ capable of handling (reading) the message in the second case, and if yes what are the required options? The exchange is durable already but it didn't help.

Comment: If a client starts first and tries to send the message but there's no server listening on the TCP 5672, how would the client be supposed to sucesfully deliver the message? There's no other end of the communication and from the client perspective - the server can be up in a second, a minute, a year or never. If I understand correctly, the client would have to maintain its own journal of undelivered messages and when the server is up, the client should deliver undelivered messages first and only then deliver consecutive messages.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, ah, sorry, choosing my words was unfortunate, in original question I used names "server/client" in sense of the roles of those parts in my program. I changed the question and used names "receiver/sender" instead, on the other hand the core/engine of RMQ (Erlang sever) runs non-stop, that is why I know the messages are sent correctly. Sorry once again for confusion.

Comment: This, on the other hand, seems easy and it always works for me. I even have a simple example, I run the producer, publish messages, I see messages waiting in the queue, I shut down the producer. I run the consumer and it consumes all messages that were in the queue.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, ok, so good news it should work. Do you remember any particular option for this scenario?

Comment: Will post a short answer for you to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple producer

```
    // producer
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() 
        { 
            HostName = "localhost"                
        };
        using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection() )
        {
            using ( var channel = connection.CreateModel() )
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare( "hello", true, false, false, null );

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( message );

                while ( true )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Press key to send message" );
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    channel.BasicPublish( "", "hello", null, body );

                    Console.WriteLine( " [x] Sent {0}", message );
                }
            }
        }
```

I run this, publish few messages and I see them all in a queue at the RMQ.

Then I run this simple consumer

```
    // consumer
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("hello", true, false, false, null);

                var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                         "To exit press CTRL+C");
                while (true)
                {
                    var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                    var body    = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I got my messages in the consumer even though it's been run **after** the producer finished.

Please verify how does this differ from your setup.

**Edit:** This also works if there's an exchange backing the queue in the producer:

```
    // producer
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() 
        { 
            HostName = "localhost"                
        };
        using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection() )
        {
            using ( var channel = connection.CreateModel() )
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare( "hello", true, false, false, null );
                channel.ExchangeDeclare( "helloe", "fanout", true );
                channel.QueueBind( "hello", "helloe", "" );

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( message );

                while ( true )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Press key to send message" );
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    channel.BasicPublish( "helloe", "", null, body );

                    Console.WriteLine( " [x] Sent {0}", message );
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine( "finished" );
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

(no changes to the consumer are necessary)

**Edit 2**: this also works when eventing consumer is used:

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("hello", true, false, false, null);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
                };
                channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

                Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                         "To exit press CTRL+C");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, I see first differences, you don't declare exchange, I on the other hand declare as durable exchange but not queue. Time for testing! :-) Thank you very much.

Comment: This also works when I have an exchange backing the queue. In fact, I've stripped down my original example. Edited my answer.

Comment: So far the only difference is using `QueueingBasicConsumer` vs `EventingBasicConsumer`, in the latter case the initial message (sent before consumer is started) are lost. Still investigating...

Comment: @astrowalker: interesting, as this seem to still works when I switch to `EventingBasicConsumer`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this time it was stupid change of mine in order, I wrote consume then subscribe :-( So thank you once again and mystery is solved, everything works now on my side as well.

Answer (score 2):

**YES**, RabbitMQ is capable of keeping those messages until your consumer becomes available. It is just a matter of when have you declared the queue, and the queue configuration.

In short; If you declare and bind your queue **before** the messages are published, the messages will be kept in that queue regardless of not having a consumer yet.

As [explained in the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.durable), some parameters affect this behavior when declaring a queue:

- `exclusive`, if true, will delete the queue (and the messages) when the consumer disconnects.
- `durable`, if true, will keep the messages even when RabbitMQ restarts.

When the consumers create and setup their own queues idempotently on startup, the situation is exactly like you describe; Messages get "lost" if the consumer has never ran.

This is somewhat a common practice as you can verify by the tutorials, especially in [a pub-sub scenario (see tutorial #3)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) where publishers don't know about the consumers or what queues they would need.

If you really want to make sure all messages are received, some means of declaring the queues beforehand is needed.